# Could not update project bookmark configuration

Tags: demoiselle

Após atualização para o demoiselle-2-infra-3 passei a ter esse problema ao criar novos projetos, até mesmo se eu criar um novo repositório ocorre o problema.

No log do eclipse consta o seguinte:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core 4 0 2015-04-15 14:38:41.204
!MESSAGE null argument:
!STACK 0
org.eclipse.core.runtime.AssertionFailedException: null argument:
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.Assert.isNotNull(Assert.java:85)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.Assert.isNotNull(Assert.java:73)
    at org.eclipse.core.expressions.EvaluationContext.addVariable(EvaluationContext.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.jst.common.project.facet.core.libprov.internal.LibraryProvider.isEnabledFor(LibraryProvider.java:273)
    at org.eclipse.jst.common.project.facet.core.libprov.LibraryInstallDelegate.refresh(LibraryInstallDelegate.java:364)
    at org.eclipse.jst.common.project.facet.core.libprov.LibraryInstallDelegate$2.handleEvent(LibraryInstallDelegate.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.internal.FacetedProjectWorkingCopy.notifyListeners(FacetedProjectWorkingCopy.java:1752)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.internal.FacetedProjectWorkingCopy.resumeEventNotification(FacetedProjectWorkingCopy.java:1797)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.internal.FacetedProjectWorkingCopy.addProjectFacet(FacetedProjectWorkingCopy.java:822)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.internal.FacetedProject$1.run(FacetedProject.java:301)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2313)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.internal.FacetedProject.modify(FacetedProject.java:339)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.wtp.jpa.internal.configurators.JpaProjectConfigurator.configureFacets(JpaProjectConfigurator.java:154)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.wtp.jpa.internal.configurators.JpaProjectConfigurator.configure(JpaProjectConfigurator.java:109)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.project.configurator.AbstractLifecycleMapping.configure(AbstractLifecycleMapping.java:120)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.ProjectConfigurationManager$3.call(ProjectConfigurationManager.java:477)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.ProjectConfigurationManager$3.call(ProjectConfigurationManager.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:166)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:142)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.ProjectConfigurationManager.updateProjectConfiguration(ProjectConfigurationManager.java:470)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.ProjectConfigurationManager.configureNewMavenProjects(ProjectConfigurationManager.java:250)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.ProjectConfigurationManager$1.call(ProjectConfigurationManager.java:163)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.ProjectConfigurationManager$1.call(ProjectConfigurationManager.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:166)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:109)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:96)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl.execute(MavenImpl.java:1348)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.ProjectConfigurationManager.importProjects(ProjectConfigurationManager.java:133)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.ProjectConfigurationManager.createArchetypeProjects0(ProjectConfigurationManager.java:789)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.ProjectConfigurationManager$5.call(ProjectConfigurationManager.java:719)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.ProjectConfigurationManager$5.call(ProjectConfigurationManager.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:166)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:142)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:96)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl.execute(MavenImpl.java:1348)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.ProjectConfigurationManager.createArchetypeProjects(ProjectConfigurationManager.java:717)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.ui.internal.wizards.MavenProjectWizard$5.doCreateMavenProjects(MavenProjectWizard.java:244)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.ui.internal.wizards.AbstactCreateMavenProjectJob$1.doCreateMavenProjects(AbstactCreateMavenProjectJob.java:46)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.ui.internal.wizards.AbstractCreateMavenProjectsOperation.run(AbstractCreateMavenProjectsOperation.java:62)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.ui.internal.wizards.AbstactCreateMavenProjectJob.runInWorkspace(AbstactCreateMavenProjectJob.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.InternalWorkspaceJob.run(InternalWorkspaceJob.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.m2e.logback.appender 2 0 2015-04-15 14:38:41.230
!MESSAGE Could not update project bookmark configuration

!ENTRY org.eclipse.m2e.core 4 0 2015-04-15 14:38:41.249
!MESSAGE Could not update project bookmark configuration
!STACK 0
org.eclipse.core.runtime.AssertionFailedException: null argument:
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.Assert.isNotNull(Assert.java:85)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.Assert.isNotNull(Assert.java:73)
    at org.eclipse.core.expressions.EvaluationContext.addVariable(EvaluationContext.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.jst.common.project.facet.core.libprov.internal.LibraryProvider.isEnabledFor(LibraryProvider.java:273)
    at org.eclipse.jst.common.project.facet.core.libprov.LibraryInstallDelegate.refresh(LibraryInstallDelegate.java:364)
    at org.eclipse.jst.common.project.facet.core.libprov.LibraryInstallDelegate.reset(LibraryInstallDelegate.java:450)
    at org.eclipse.jst.common.project.facet.core.libprov.LibraryInstallDelegate.<init>(LibraryInstallDelegate.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.core.internal.facet.JpaFacetDataModelProvider.buildDefaultLibraryProvider(JpaFacetDataModelProvider.java:237)
    at org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.core.internal.facet.JpaFacetDataModelProvider.getDefaultLibraryProvider(JpaFacetDataModelProvider.java:209)
    at org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.core.internal.facet.JpaFacetDataModelProvider.getDefaultProperty(JpaFacetDataModelProvider.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.core.internal.facet.JpaFacetInstallDataModelProvider.getDefaultProperty(JpaFacetInstallDataModelProvider.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.frameworks.internal.datamodel.DataModelImpl.getProperty(DataModelImpl.java:130)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.frameworks.datamodel.AbstractDataModelProvider.getProperty(AbstractDataModelProvider.java:218)
    at org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.core.internal.facet.JpaFacetDataModelProvider.getLibraryInstallDelegate(JpaFacetDataModelProvider.java:111)
    at org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.core.internal.facet.JpaFacetDataModelProvider.adjustLibraryProviders(JpaFacetDataModelProvider.java:391)
    at org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.core.internal.facet.JpaFacetDataModelProvider.propertySet(JpaFacetDataModelProvider.java:295)
    at org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.core.internal.facet.JpaFacetInstallDataModelProvider.propertySet(JpaFacetInstallDataModelProvider.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.frameworks.internal.datamodel.DataModelImpl.internalSetProperty(DataModelImpl.java:182)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.frameworks.internal.datamodel.DataModelImpl.setProperty(DataModelImpl.java:172)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.componentcore.datamodel.FacetDataModelConfigAdapter.setProjectFacetVersion(FacetDataModelConfigAdapter.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.internal.FacetedProjectWorkingCopy.bindProjectFacetActionConfig(FacetedProjectWorkingCopy.java:1529)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.internal.FacetedProjectWorkingCopy.createProjectFacetAction(FacetedProjectWorkingCopy.java:1464)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.internal.FacetedProjectWorkingCopy.refreshProjectFacetActions(FacetedProjectWorkingCopy.java:1558)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.internal.FacetedProjectWorkingCopy.setProjectFacets(FacetedProjectWorkingCopy.java:777)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.internal.FacetedProjectWorkingCopy.addProjectFacet(FacetedProjectWorkingCopy.java:807)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.internal.FacetedProject$1.run(FacetedProject.java:301)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2313)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.internal.FacetedProject.modify(FacetedProject.java:339)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.wtp.jpa.internal.configurators.JpaProjectConfigurator.configureFacets(JpaProjectConfigurator.java:154)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.wtp.jpa.internal.configurators.JpaProjectConfigurator.configure(JpaProjectConfigurator.java:109)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.project.configurator.AbstractLifecycleMapping.configure(AbstractLifecycleMapping.java:120)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.ProjectConfigurationManager$3.call(ProjectConfigurationManager.java:477)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.ProjectConfigurationManager$3.call(ProjectConfigurationManager.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:166)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:142)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.ProjectConfigurationManager.updateProjectConfiguration(ProjectConfigurationManager.java:470)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.ProjectConfigurationManager.configureNewMavenProjects(ProjectConfigurationManager.java:250)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.ProjectConfigurationManager$1.call(ProjectConfigurationManager.java:163)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.ProjectConfigurationManager$1.call(ProjectConfigurationManager.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:166)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:109)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:96)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl.execute(MavenImpl.java:1348)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.ProjectConfigurationManager.importProjects(ProjectConfigurationManager.java:133)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.ProjectConfigurationManager.createArchetypeProjects0(ProjectConfigurationManager.java:789)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.ProjectConfigurationManager$5.call(ProjectConfigurationManager.java:719)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.ProjectConfigurationManager$5.call(ProjectConfigurationManager.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:166)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:142)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:96)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl.execute(MavenImpl.java:1348)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.ProjectConfigurationManager.createArchetypeProjects(ProjectConfigurationManager.java:717)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.ui.internal.wizards.MavenProjectWizard$5.doCreateMavenProjects(MavenProjectWizard.java:244)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.ui.internal.wizards.AbstactCreateMavenProjectJob$1.doCreateMavenProjects(AbstactCreateMavenProjectJob.java:46)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.ui.internal.wizards.AbstractCreateMavenProjectsOperation.run(AbstractCreateMavenProjectsOperation.java:62)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.ui.internal.wizards.AbstactCreateMavenProjectJob.runInWorkspace(AbstactCreateMavenProjectJob.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.InternalWorkspaceJob.run(InternalWorkspaceJob.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
```

Comment: Qual é o sistema operacional que está usando? e que versão? Você comentou que fez a atualização do pacote. Você está usando o mesmo workspace da versão anterior?

Comment: Então sistema operacional Ubuntu 14.04 64bits, demoiselle-2-infra-3 + ireport, o workspace eu criei um novo para me certificar que o erro não era por usar um workspace antigo, também usei o archetype demoiselle-jsf-jpa 2.4.2, usando o archetype demoiselle-minimal não tive problemas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parece que está acontecendo algum erro na geração do projeto pelo arquétipo, através do plugin do maven.

Se o projeto está visível na área de trabalho do Eclipse, a primeira medida é (selecionando o projeto) clicando com o botão direito do mouse selecionar os menus: Maven -> Update Project...  Marcando também a opção Force Update of Snapshots/Releases

Se isso não resolver, ou se o projeto não estiver aparecendo na área de trabalho indica que os fontes do arquétipo podem estar corrompidos no seu repositório local.

Um primeiro teste para verificar se é o fonte da versão, é criar um projeto com uma versão anterior, como por exemplo: 2.4.0 ou 2.4.1

Se não houver problemas com versões anteriores, para resolver isso na 2.4.2, infelizmente é preciso uma certa "força bruta". E para isso vá até o diretório: /opt/demoiselle/tool/maven-repo/br/gov/frameworkdemoiselle/archetypes/demoiselle-jsf-jpa/ neste diretório deve aparecer a pasta com a versão que está executando. Apague o diretório da versão: /2.4.2
Feito isso, execute novamente o procedimento de criação do projeto.

Comment: Olá Saito, tentei o procedimento e mesmo assim o erro persiste, tentei deletar a pasta br/ do meu repositório e mesmo erro, tentei usar o repositório da web e também erro.

Comment: Olá Saito, fiz um teste em outra instancia do eclipse que não é ligada ao repositório do demoiselle e funcionou a criação do projeto, ou seja, o problema está no eclipse do demoiselle

Comment: Neste caso, experimentou desinstalar e reinstalar o Eclipse? Muito usam esse mesmo pacote e é primeira vez que relatam isso. Pode ser então que o próprio Eclipse foi corrompido. Mas, já saiu outra versão ( 4.2.2 ) do Eclipse que em breve atualizaremos.

Comment: Então Saito, reinstalei a versão do zero e o erro persistiu, bom fui procurar nos bugs do eclipse e me deparei com a configuração "Maven -> Java EE Integration -> JPA Configurator", o que acontece aqui é que ao realizar o update por faltar alguma configuração para o eclipse essa gera o erro, pois bem entrei nas configurações do projeto e setei o runtime e após adicionei o jpa setando como plataform "Generic 2.1" e jpa implementation "Library provided by target runtime" assim parou o erro e o update correu normalmente.

Comment: Obrigado pelo retorno Gustavo. Vamos verificar essas configurações na próxima versão.